# How to use baseUrl in SCSS with Rollup?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, rollup

I have project:
React + Typescript + SCSS + Rollup

Folders:

```
src
--components
--scss
----variables.scss
```

In `tsconfig.js` I added `"baseUrl": "./src",`.
And in my .scss file, I want to import `variables.scss`.
I tried something like `@import '~scss/variables';` but got the error. How can I use imports in my .scss files using baseUrl?